# dynamic loading content containing javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to add a progress bar before my web page's content loads, so I thought of loading it dynamically via javascript. This content has embedded javascript in its html. I tried using jquery.load() which works perfectly besides the fact that it does not support the js that doesn''t work on the returned content

just to make it clear, what i'm doing is something like this to load all the content:

```
 $("#contentid").html("progressBar.gif");
 $("#contentid").load(script.php #content)
 $("#contentid").show();
```

and inside the content returned from script.php there are js calls such as:

```
jquery.load (to crawl for data and displaying it when ready)
document.getElementById('some_div') (for chart api)
snippets that load widgets
```

I've been trying to work around with using jquery.ajax though not sure if\how its possible with it yet. would love for some input on that.should i be able to achieve that with it?

Any other idea that might show a progress bar till the script's content is loaded will be great. I'm trying to reduce changes in the code structure, since this long load happens only sometimes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a div with the progress bar, covering all the page, and remove it after the page is loaded, using:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#progressbar').remove();
});
```

Comment: but the DIV with the progree bar wont be shown since the script hasn't returned yet to the client.  unless i don't understand you correctly? if the progress bar's DIV is part of the script, it wont be shown until it finishes...

Comment: Oh. Don't load the page dynamically for this.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's load method takes a callback function as an argument.  That function will get called when the load is completed, so you can hide your progress bar at that point.  Here is an example from their [API docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  alert('Load was performed.');
});
```

In your case, it would be something like:

```
$("#contentid").load(script.php, function(){
  $("#contentid").hide();
});
```

Comment: but as i mentioned, the jquery load doesn't support embedded javascript, which is what i have.

Comment: Can provide add some sample code to show us what you are trying to load into your page?

Comment: its pretty long. just some script that crawls for data via external apis, parses it, analyzes it, and displays it, with some js enhancements. i just want to leave it as a closed module, that the main page loads, while showing a progress bar. It's basically the site's content, which on certain cases takes a lot of time to load

Comment: You might need a combination of jQuery.get and jQuery.append.  It is hard for me to give you a more detailed suggestion, because it is a little ambiguous when you say "embedded javascript in its html".  I don't need to see the whole thing, just a snippet or something similar to your code.

Comment: i use $('#picCon').jquery.load(crawlpic.php) to call some simple scripts that crawls for pics. I do a document.getElementById('some_div') when i use the google charts api. I also have a js snippet for some very basic 'tweet' widget. that's pretty much the picture

Comment: What is in crawlpic.php?  Is it just JavaScript, does it have JavaScript within script tags, or is it a mix of HTML and JavaScript?  If it is just JavaScript, then you should use JQuery to add a script tag element to the end of the HTML body, with the src set to the URL of your script.  That should load and execute your script.  Separately, you can still use the callback from jQuery.load to know when the script has been retrieved.  In that case, jQuery.load will have nothing to do with actually adding the script into your page and executing it.